# Detecting KeyStrokes

Tags: c#, keystroke

Hi i am considering adding some functionality to my app that allows the user to highlight any piece of text on a given page be it pdf or browser or word or what not. Then with the right keystroke i would like to send that down to my application running in the bottom right hand corner that has a text box.

I was wondering (seeing as i am a placement student and not yet graduated) how hard this would be and what i would need to research?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows, take a look at the Win32 API. Here's an example:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shrijeetnair/win32api12062005005528AM/win32api.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice project here: [System Hotkey Component](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/systemhotkey.aspx?df=100&forumid=12637&exp=0&select=663478)

This project allows your application to sit in the system tray/notification area and fires off an event whenever a hot key of your choosing is detected. In addition, its written in C#. Using this project, making what you are trying to make should be simple.